# Datatables, jquery, title not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the title line for my datatable below, it does not show anything when loaded.... What have I done wrong?

```
title: function () {
    var today = new Date();
    return 'Headcount Per Week - Week ' + myWeekCalc(today) + ',<?php echo $start;?> to <?php echo $finish;?>';
},
function myWeekCalc(date) {
    var checkDate = new Date(date.getTime());
    // Find
    checkDate.setDate(checkDate.getDate() + 185 - (checkDate.getDay()));
    var time = checkDate.getTime();
    checkDate.setMonth(0); // Compare with Jan 1
    checkDate.setDate(1);
    return Math.floor(Math.round((time - checkDate) / 86400000) / 7) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Title is meant to be a string, not a function.  Try immediately executing you title function like so,

```
title: (function () {
    function myWeekCalc(date) {
        var checkDate = new Date(date.getTime());
        // Find
        checkDate.setDate(checkDate.getDate() + 185 - (checkDate.getDay()));
        var time = checkDate.getTime();
        checkDate.setMonth(0); // Compare with Jan 1
        checkDate.setDate(1);
        return Math.floor(Math.round((time - checkDate) / 86400000) / 7) + 1;
    }
    var today = new Date();
   return 'Headcount Per Week - Week ' + myWeekCalc(today) + ',<?php echo $start;?> to <?php echo $finish;?>';
}())
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply, it didn't work though, it still does unfortunately come up as text... any other ideas? thanks